# How to restrict usage of internal methods from Android Room Dao

Tags: android, kotlin, interface, android-room

I have a [Transaction](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Transaction) in Room like this given in the docs.

```
@Dao
abstract class SongDao {
    @Insert
    abstract fun insert(song: Song)
    @Delete
    abstract fun delete(song: Song)
    @Transaction
    fun insertAndDeleteInTransaction(newSong: Song, oldSong: Song) {
        // Anything inside this method runs in a single transaction.
        insert(newSong)
        delete(oldSong)
    }
}
```

My use-case is I don't want to expose `delete()` in Dao to be called from outside the Dao.
**Is it possible? If yes, how?**

Making the method `private` is not an option since `private` methods are not allowed in the interface in Kotlin.

Comment: try use protected I tried it and got no error compiling

Comment: @MuhammadAliJr, `Modifier 'protected' is not applicable inside 'interface'`. Reference - https://pl.kotl.in/YEe_DepBC

Answer (score 0):

You can, from an instance of the built database, get a SupportSQLiteDatabase via the openHelper function and use either the delete, execSQL or query functions.

e.g. along the lines of:-

```
    db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
    db.openHelper.writableDatabase.delete("the_table","the_column=?", arrayOf("the_value"))
    db.openHelper.writableDatabase.execSQL("DELETE FROM the_table WHERE the_column =?", arrayOf("the_value"))
    db.openHelper.writableDatabase.query("DELETE FROM the_table, WHERE the_column =?", arrayOf("the_value"))
```

- obviously you would only use one of the above,
- also the above is just a example,
- Note that as these are outside the scope of Room compile time checking for the validity of the SQL then you could experience run time errors if the SQL is incorrect e.g. the incorrect table name.

An example use based upon your code and an embedded Song data class:-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDao
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getAllDao()

        insertAndDeleteInTransaction(Song(songName = "The Song"),Song(100,"whatever"))
    }

    private fun insertAndDeleteInTransaction(newSong: Song, oldSong: Song ) {
        val helper=db.openHelper.writableDatabase
        helper.beginTransaction()
        val newSongRowid = dao.insert(newSong)
        val numberOfSongsDeleted = helper.delete("song","songId=?", arrayOf(oldSong.songid))
        helper.setTransactionSuccessful() /* IF not set then changes would be rolled back */
        helper.endTransaction()
    }

    @Entity
    data class Song(
        @PrimaryKey
        var songid: Long?=null,
        var songName: String
    )
}
```

- obviously the Song class would not be defined within the Activity, it's inclusion here is just for the example
- The oldSong has a songName called whatever, this to indicate that it doesn't matter what the song name is. It is the PrimaryKey that is used to ascertain which row is to be deleted.

  - in this example you can see that the songId is the primary key, and it is assumed that a song with the songId 100 exists (if not then numberOfSongsDelete would be 0 i.e. DELETE does not fail if there is nothing to delete)
- The insert uses the insert function in the @Dao annotated interface/abstract class.
- Note that newSongRowid will be the rowid of the inserted row or -1 if for some reason the row could not be inserted and the was not a failure.

**rowid**

All tables (with some rare exceptions) have a column called rowid. In the case of the Song table as the primary key **songId** is a integer type (Long, Int, Byte ....) then it is an alias of the rowid.

Hence the insert above of the newSong, which doesn't specify a value for the songId, will have the value generated (no need for `autoGenerate = true`).

- for example if the last song inserted was the song with an id of 100, then the songId of the newSong would probably be 101.

You may wish to refer to https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html and also https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html (if you use autoGenerate=true, AUTOINCREMENT is applied)

Comment: I am already aware of manually writing SLQ and creating transactions. I am looking out for this in Room Dao.